# In Polkadot Apps developer tab how do you encode a Rust tuple?

Tags: substrate, polkadot-js

There are several examples for including custom Rust types declared in a runtime module that can be applied Polkadot Apps interface [here](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/settings/developer). However I am not sure how to encode tuples. This would also be the case for anyone else planning on using Tuples in their code and runtime API for use in polkadot-js.

Here's how it is declared in a Substrate Runtime module:

```rust
// tuple (struct)
pub type Code = u16;
pub type Type = u16;
pub struct Tuple(Code, Type);

// Complex struct using tuple
pub struct Record<T::AccountId,Tuple> {
    pub address: T::AccountId,
    pub tuple_values: Tuple,
}

// Storage
Record get(record):
        map T::AccountId => Option<Record<T::AccountId,Tuple>>;
```

I am presuming I would add something like this to the `Developer` tab in the Polkadot Apps settings, but I don't know if this is the correct syntax to use.

```
{
    "Code": "u16",
    "Type": "u16",
    "Tuple": ["Code", "Type"],
    "Record": {
        "address": "AccountId",
        "tuple_values": "Tuple"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuples, Tuple structs, and Named structs are all encoded the same way. From [https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/scale-codec#tuples](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/scale-codec#tuples%E2%80%AF) :

> **Tuples** A fixed-size series of values, each with a possibly different but predetermined and fixed type. This is simply the concatenation of each encoded value.
> …
> For structures, the values are named, but that is irrelevant for the encoding (names are ignored - only order matters).

So in your case something like this will work:

```json
{
    "Code": "u16",
    "Type": "u16",
    "Tuple": {
        "bogus_name_1": "Code",
        "bogus_name_2": "Type"
    },
    "Record": {
        "address": "AccountId",
        "tuple_values": "Tuple"
    }
}
```